# DDR2 quality vs quantity

Tags: memory, ddr2

I have an older computer that I want to upgrade.  Currently it can run Left 4 Dead 2, but it's a little jittery.

It has 1G x 2 of ddr2 800 ram.  I have some extra 512 x 2 ddr2 533 ram.

So my question will it be worth it to use the 533 ram to upgrade to 3G of ram but possibly drop the data rate to 533?  Or would it better to stick with 2G of ram but running at it's full 800 data rate?

---

**Extra info**: I'm also looking at upgrading the CPU and Graphics card, but it would be nice to get a performance boost for free with my extra ddr2.

MoBo: `mcp61pm-am`, a generic OEM board, nothing special, 4 dimms for ddr2 and one pci-express slot

CPU: `Athlon 64 X2 3800+`,  Not terrible for when it was bought.

Graphics: `NVidia nForce 430`,  integrated graphics card.  Not really meant for games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding more ram is important than the mhz of rams iff you do really fully  use all the 2 gb ram but if not you should consider 800mhz (( but i guess, speed difference can't be understand between 533 and 800 mhz ))  ... by the way upgrading graphic card is the most important thing to do for the games. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your mobo has dual channel, you might consider adding the 533 RAM as well. Some mobo's then lower all the RAM to that, some don't. Best to check its status in the BIOS and see how your mobo reacts.

But why not just buy another 1GB DDR2 800Mhz strip if it doesn't work? It'll just be a few bucks.